# Allowed memory size of 134217728 … wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1989

Tags: plugins, php

While accessing WordPress dashboard>

Fatal error: The allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes) in /home/paleobri/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1989

I updated memory_limit on PHP.ini top 512M.
But not working
Can anyone help?

Comment: Did the 134217728 number change when you increased the limit, or not? If the number is still roughly 134000000 then however you increased the limit didn't work, and you'll need to speak to your host.

Comment: Number not changed increasing the limit.

Comment: Then the increase didn’t take. You need to speak to your host.